# How to use layer instruction into videoCompositionWithAsset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler method

Tags: ios, avfoundation

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this
>   issue:
>
> CoreImage filtering and layer instruction based composition can't be
>   used simultaneously. Layer instructions won't be run when added to an
>   AVMutableVideoComposition that it is initialized with
>   +[videoCompositionWithAsset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:]. To use layer instructions in this case, move the functionality into the
>   handler instead of adding the layer instructions to the
>   AVMutableVideoComposition.

This is what i found from apple engineer. It says To use layer instructions in this case, move the functionality into the handler instead of adding the layer instructions to the AVMutableVideoComposition. But don't know how it can be!

Please help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: have you found solution? Hit_Var