# How can I add a filter to an AVComposition that has merged movie assets and layer instructions

Tags: ios, avfoundation

The app I am working on edits video files and merges them into an AVComposition.
This is done in a pretty straight forward way that has been well documented:
Create a AVMutableComposition...
Create Video and Audio tracks.
Insert video and audio segments onto these tracks.
Create an AVVideoComposition object. Populate it with layer instructions.

I am now interested in adding filters to my AVComposition (to be presented in an AVPlayer and later to be exported to an mp4 file).

The only way to add a filter to an AVComposition I was able to find, was to use the AVMutableVideoComposition's videoCompositionWithAsset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler initializer.

However, as others have noted, initializing the AVMutableVideoComposition this way does not allow to later add the necessary layer instructions.

More so, I cannot find a way to specify a start point and duration for the assigned filter (but this is less of a problem for me at this point).

All the resources I've found on using filters in AVFoundation do not use merged videos, rather apply the filter on one video asset.
I have tried using the AVComposition as that asset, but without being able to use my layer instructions, the result is useless.

Any idea how I can create such a composition that merges videos and is also able to apply a filter (sepia..., brightness, etc..).

Thanks

I found this link but it is not clear:
[How to use layer instruction into videoCompositionWithAsset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040808/how-to-use-layer-instruction-into-videocompositionwithassetapplyingcifilterswit)

When attempting to initialize the

I get the following error/exception:

> [AVCoreImageFilterCustomVideoCompositor startVideoCompositionRequest:] Expecting video composition to contain only AVCoreImageFilterVideoCompositionInstruction'

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem and can't find a solution, so I started a bounty.